# What are some good miRNA databases?

Tags: python, proteins, genomics, rna, genetics

I am writing a project proposal for my boss and it is on codon usage bias in the dystrophin protein and the spectrin-like repeats found in a hmmscan file using the longest dystrophin isoform protein sequence which I got from a GenBank file!

There is a lot of research on how mRNA and tRNA impact codon usage bias and codon frequency.  Long story short, I work at a gene therapy lab as a bioinformatician doing research for muscular dystrophy.  Our lab is very interested in miRNA, and I have found a certain amount of articles that show miRNA may impact codon usage bias since miRNA can either cleave or translationally repress mRNA.

I found a miRNA database called [www.tools4mirs.org](http://www.tools4mirs.org). It seems like a potentially good database, but I don't know if it's the right database geared for this project.  We saw some unusual lack of protein expression when there should be a lot of protein expression and our lab is really focused on an interested in miRNAs.

Are there any other miRNA databases/tools that you can recommend?

I code in Python and know some AI/ML and would like to make this project a AI/ML bioinformatics project, but I do not know what some good miRNA databases are, since I want to pull large amounts of miRNA data for my project that is relative to muscular dystrophy.

So to sum up my question, what are some really heavily and well-curated miRNA databases besides tools4mirs.org ? I am kind of new to this field, and would like to hear any suggestion since I am still learning the inner workings of the field of bioinformatics and the possibilities and directions it can go in.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would first use Ncbi's SRA. Every miRNA study will need to upload there and I'd use the sratoolkit.

Comment: Good databases for what? What kind of data do you need? Sequences? Functional annotations? Variants? Population data? What species? A specific one? Any? What does protein expression have to do with it?

Comment: miRNA databases with functional annotations and structural annotations for humans is what I am looking for.  I am looking at the concept of translation/reverse translation and miRNA regulation of mRNA which impacts tRNA/anti-codons